# Trying to convert a string into an integer in PHP, but it returns 0

Tags: php, types, casting

I need to get the user's screen width and work with it in PHP, but you can't get the screen width with PHP so I'm using Javascript for that and trying to pass the value as an integer to PHP.

Everything I've read says you need to do that by passing the value to the URL and then PHP can access it through $_GET, but I need to do it in another way. The method I figured out seems to work except for returning a 0 when I try to turn it into an integer.

**Here's my code:**

```
<?php
$sWidth = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.write(screen.width);</script>";
?>
```

$sWidth gets the value but it's a string. I've tried a few different casting methods but everything returns 0.

How can I turn the string into an integer using the above method?

Comment: Looks like you need some AJAX

Comment: Php variables are not locked down to one type. `$var = '3';` That variable can now be used as both string and integer. Its not like C++/Java. You don't have to convert. But obviously if you put javascript in a variable PHP is not going to evaluate the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is rendered on the server before the data is transferred to the client. You cannot get the screen width without the client specifically sending it to the server say as a GET or POST 
parameter.

Hence an ajax call could do the trick. Or a reload with an extra ?swidth=xxx GET parameter.
i.e.

```
$sWidth = isset($_GET['swidth']) ? $_GET['swidth'] : '';
```